# Two files of same size are having totally different size after compression using 7zip

Tags: 7zip, compression

Two csv files of 3 GB each are compressed using 7zip. After compression one file is having size of 242 MB and other is of 141 MB. How this is possible?

Both files contains same data format. However, data can be different.

Please let me know is anything which is the reason of higher compressed file size i.e. 242 MB.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert of compression, but I think that it depends strongly of the content before compression. For example, if there are many repetitions of sequences in one file, it will be easy to compress it, but if there are few, the compression won't be able to do as well.

For example, a 3GB text file containing the same words many times will be significantly smaller after compression, but a ZIP file of 3GB will not become smaller and may event be larger after compressing it.

Answer (score 1):

Content of files is significant in compression. Basicaly the more redundant data is in file the smaller this file can be after compression. Here is really nice explanation how compression works: https://computer.howstuffworks.com/file-compression.htm